# Dynamic input focus out when entering text into input box Angular 11

Tags: angular11, formgroups

I have add dynamic element using formGroup in Angular 11

but when I enter some text input will focus out.

[dynamic input added on check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOAgw.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add a minimum reproducible example with https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my bug and resolve it after loop through on form array

```
<div formArrayName="permissions" *ngFor="let perm of formArr.controls; let i = index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value" placeholder="Value">
            <small class=" form-text text-danger" *ngIf="(!form.get('value').valid) || form.get('value').touched">
              <span *ngIf="form.get('value').errors?.required">This feild is required.</span>
            </small>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!i;else content">
            <i class="ti-plus text-primary pointer" (click)="addNewRow()"></i>
          </div>

          <ng-template #content>
            <i class="ti-trash text-danger pointer" (click)="deleteRow(i)"></i>
          </ng-template>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```